# VBA runtime error 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_global'

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete from file list.xlsm rows that are meeting in file wrongemails.csv.

I have a script:

```
Sub DelRows()
Dim ra As Range, delra As Range
Dim Arr() As Variant
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    Arr = Range("[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$1:[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$4000")
     For Each ra In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        For Each word In Arr
        If Not ra.Find(word, , xlValues, xlPart) Is Nothing Then            
           If delra Is Nothing Then Set delra = ra Else Set delra = Union(delra, ra)
        End If
        Next word
    Next
    If Not delra Is Nothing Then delra.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

But when I try to use it, I have an runtime error 1004:

```
**Method 'Range' of object'_global'**
```

in line

```
Arr = Range("[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$1:[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$4000")
```

Files list.xlsm and wrongemails.csv are in the same folder.

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: you would need wrongemails to be open, also you haven't dimmed `word`

Comment: When reporting an error you should state on which line it appears.

Comment: Hi Tatiana, it's actually quite hard to tell what's wrong with your script. As SJR pointed out, please edit your question to include which line the error occurs on.

Comment: Error apears in line 
Arr = Range("[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$1:[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$4000")

Comment: What about this, assuming the file is open `Arr = Workbooks("wrongemails.csv").Worksheets("wrongemails").Range("$A$1:$A$4000")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Arr = Range("[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$1:[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$4000")
```

Use:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$1:[wrongemails.csv]wrongemails!$A$4000")
```

Change Sheet1 to actual name of "Sheet1"

Comment: The range is using an External address.  `wrongemails.csv` is the  workbook and  `wrongemails` is the worksheet.